# Foreground chart by mouse

Tags: chart.js

type: 'scatter'
Now first one is on the top. Is it possible to show different charts on the top?
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gjbX.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your dataset array you can put a type to put a different type in there. The order of the datasets in the array decide the draw order of them.

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 13, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        type: 'bar',
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'red'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          reverse: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js" integrity="sha512-hZf9Qhp3rlDJBvAKvmiG+goaaKRZA6LKUO35oK6EsM0/kjPK32Yw7URqrq3Q+Nvbbt8Usss+IekL7CRn83dYmw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```